# How can I log a dictionary without seeing the {}?

Tags: javascript, hash

Here is my code:

```
const items = {
    string: "String",
    number: 12
};
```

This is the output when I use `console.log(items);`

```
{ string: 'String', number: 12 }
```

How can I make it so that when I use `console.log(items);`, it returns this:

```
string: "String"
number: 12
```

Comment: What have you tried already? There are probably hundreds of ways to do this. The simplest way would be to turn it into an array of key/value pairs, then just join with a newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one potential way to loop through all properties of an object and log them as you're requesting.

```
for (let i in items) {
  if (items.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    console.log(i + ": " + items[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well , you defined items as object and this is how the console prints Objects . 
You can make your own function that will print in the format you would like .

the function will get object as input and iterate throw its fields for printing .

Comment: Can you provide an example, that is what the question is for.